How does GA4 work without a local database?
I'm quite new to Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and Google Ads (GAds) and am trying to understand the basics. Because of upcoming strict privacy laws in the European Union, that is important to me.
On https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11397207?hl=en, it says that GA4 only uses first-party cookies and does not send data to the Google server. It becomes a different story when the GA4 account is linked to a GAds account, but without that, you should be able to get metrics like unique visitors during the last 12 months without data having been sent to the Google server. (If I'm wrong here, please let me know.)
Their competitor Mamoto can work that way as well, but then needs a local-server MySQL database to be able to present such metrics. How does GA4 do that, regarding that it does not require such a local database?

You've read that page wrong. It says it uses first party cookies, but that it doesn't need to set cookies to send data to Google Analytics. There is no way to not send data back to Google when using GA4. Matomo allows you to set up your local service instead of using their central one if you want to have full control of the data but GA4 doesn't have that option.

@Karl-JohanSjögren - Ah, that's it! Now I understand. Thanks a lot. If you put it into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.
